# ActionLink not calling Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an action link defined in my View

```
@Html.ActionLink("Mark as Completed", "MarkComplete", new { id = item.ID })
```

However this does not call the method in my controller, instead the link it produces the following link

http://localhost:52069/Users/MarkComplete/3

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult MarkComplete(int? id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
        Task task = db.Tasks.Find(id);
        if (task == null) {
            return HttpNotFound();
            }
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            task.Completed = 1;
            db.Entry(task).State = EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
        return View(task);
        }
```

Anything I'm missing here

Full View code

```
@model IEnumerable<Base.Models.Task> @{
    ViewBag.Title = "UserTasks"; }

<h2>User</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <h4>Task for User</h4>
        <table class="table">
            <tr>  
                <th>
                    Name
                </th>
                <th>
                    Details
                </th>
                <th>
                    Start Date
                </th>
                <th>
                    Due Date
                </th>
             </tr>
                    @foreach (var item in Model) {
                <tr>
                    <td>@item.Name </td>
                    <td>@item.Details</td>
                    <td>@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>@item.EndDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.ActionLink("Mark as Completed", "MarkComplete", new { id = item.ID })
                    </td>
                </tr>
                        }
                </table>
    }
            <div>
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
            </div>

            @section Scripts {
                @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            }
```

Comment: Remove the `[HttpPost]` attribute (a link makes a GET, not a POST). Vut since your method is changing data - it should be a POST, and in the view, use a form. You can also remove `if (ModelState.IsValid) {` - your not binding to a model, so its always `true`

Comment: Remove the existing form, and for each item, use `@using (Html.BeginForm("MarkComplete", "yourController", new { id = item.ID })) { @Html.AntiForgeryToken() <input type="submit value="Mark as Completed" /> }`. Also consider using ajax so the user can stay on the page and continue to 'Mark as Completed' other items.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your action is marked with the `HttpPost` attribute while an `ActionLink` produces a `GET` request. To be more precise, the `ActionLink` renders an anchor tag which when clicked sends a `GET` request to the server.

Is there any particular reason why the action is marked with the `HttpPost` attribute? You may want to remove the attribute or substitute it with an `HttpGet` attribute.

If it is, for some reasons, required that the action is listening to `POST` requests only, then instead of using `ActionLink` you may have a form with a single button styled as a link.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("MarkComplete", "Users")) {
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.ID">
    <input type="submit" value="Mark as Completed" />
}
```

However you have already wrapped the whole table inside of a form and yeah, the forms cannot be nested so you would need to change the view more dramatically.

So the whole view may look like this:

```
@model IEnumerable<Base.Models.Task>
@{ ViewBag.Title = "UserTasks"; }

<h2>User</h2>

<h4>Task for User</h4>
<table class="table">
    <tr>  
        <th>
            Name
        </th>
        <th>
             Details
        </th>
        <th>
            Start Date
        </th>
        <th>
            Due Date
        </th>
    </tr>
    @foreach (var item in Model) {
        <tr>
            <td>@item.Name </td>
            <td>@item.Details</td>
            <td>@item.StartDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>@item.EndDate.ToShortDateString()</td>
            <td>
                @using(Html.BeginForm("MarkComplete", "Users")) {
                    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@item.ID">
                    <input type="submit" value="Mark as Completed" />
                }
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: I have the `HTTPPost` attribute as this method will be updating data

Comment: @Darkestlyrics Good. Then you'll need a form and use `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`. Otherwise there's no benefit of having it as a POST since your call is not going to have any body.

Comment: Tried your method, clicking the button there resets the view (no task) however it doesn't seem like it's hitting the MarkComplete Method in my controller (breakpoints not getting hit)

Comment: So I figured out what was wrong, it points to a different Controller, but this answer put me onto that way of thinking.

Comment: @Darkestlyrics, ah sorry man, silly mistake in my code. Please, provide also the controller just after the action name in the BeginForm method - is it "UsersController" in your case? So it may look like: `Html.BeginForm("MarkComplete", "Users")`

Comment: @Darkestlyrics glad to hear that :)

Answer (score 0):

Replace the ActionLink with

```
<input type="submit" value="Mark as Completed">
```

so it does a POST.

Set the Form's Action to where the ActionLink points.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-4-handling-form-edit-and-post-scenarios