# @Html.ActionLink from PartialView not finding my controller action

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

Im trying to create an actionlink to download a file. I get the values of noticiaId and filename in the view but not in the controller.
There's something wrong with the actionlink HTML helper that Im missing.
If I do it this way:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAnexo", "NoticiasController", new { noticiaid = Model.ID, filename = f.File }, null)
```

I get  HTTP 404 with this URL: localhost:port/NoticiasController/DownloadAnexo?noticiaid=55&filename=file.png
This looks correct to me but still Im getting 404 errors saying that the route was not found.

Partial View:

```
@model Web.Models.Noticias.NoticiaVM
<div class="col">
        
        <label>Anexos:</label>
        <table>
            @if (Model.Anexos != null)
            {
                foreach (var f in Model.Anexos)
                {
                    <tr>
                        <td>@f.File</td>
                        <td>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAnexo", "NoticiasController", new { noticiaid = Model.ID, filename = f.File }, null)
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            }
        </table>
    </div>
```

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult DownloadAnexo(int? noticiaid, string filename)
    {
        if(noticiaid != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(filename))
        {
            string fullPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["NoticiasFiles"] + "/N_" + noticiaid + "/Anexos/";
            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(fullPath);
            return File(fileBytes, System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, filename);
        }
        else
            return Content("");
    }
```

I've also tried this:

```
<a href="@Url.Action("DownloadAnexo", "NoticiasController", 
     new { noticiaId = Model.ID, filename = f.File })">
 Download
</a>
```

But i got the same result.
I'm don't have much experience with partialviews, so I'm wondering if just because im sending data from a partial directly to the controller that might not be possible or something. IDK.

Please Help.

Comment: You make your question much more confusing by mixing up terminology. `localhost:port/NoticiasController/DownloadAnexo?noticiaid=55&filename=file.png` is a URL, not a route, and `@Html.ActionLink` is a HTML helper, not a [tag helper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/intro?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: Do you have `[HttpPost]` on `DownloadAnexo`?

Comment: Sorry about the terminology. I'll need to do better on that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes i have HttpPost

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ActionLink not calling Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38394058/actionlink-not-calling-controller)

Comment: It's giving a 404 page when i click the Download link. It's not even hitting the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a typo, NoticiasController should be Noticias

```
@Html.ActionLink("Download", "DownloadAnexo", "Noticias", new { noticiaid = Model.ID, filename = f.File }, null)
```

and fix action too

```
public ActionResult DownloadAnexo([FromQuery] int? noticiaid, [FromQuery]string filename)
```

Comment: Ye. just saw that. I'm sorry for wasting your time. Thank you.

Comment: @JuniorDevCaput If that worked for you, then you [lied](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679279/html-actionlink-from-partialview-not-finding-my-controller-action#comment121374134_68679279) about having `[HttpPost]` on `DownloadAnexo`.

Comment: @GSerg I tried everthing. It was just a damn typo. With or without it it wasn't hitting the action so that wasn't the problem I was having. Thank you for the tips on that by the way.